# How to act on just one hoverable element?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a list with several sublists inside. When I hover over a `<li>` element, I want to change the style of just that `<li>`, not the style of also its parents.

You can [check the code and demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ww5nxt3r/). If you hover over `1.1`, I just want `1.1` to be red. If I hover over `1.3.1`, I just want `1.3.1` to be red.

What do I have to change on the CSS to accomplish this?

thanks!

Comment: You can't do that with CSS because you can't hover the child LI without hovering the parent LI, you can only overwrite the children behaviour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this situation why you don't use ":hover" with "a" element?

```
   li {
      display: block;
      width: 100px;
      background-color: #dedede;
    }

    ul > li > a:hover {
       color: red;
       display: block;
    }
```

Comment: Beat me to it by 21 seconds.

Comment: I'm not sure if this solution is good for fejsa. Now when cursor is to the right of "a" element, then cursor is :hover li element but font color doesn't change.

Comment: @pigmej That was my first try, but I wanted to detect the hover on the full "<li>", not just the "<a>". However, you got me thinking again and I can add a "display:block" on the "<a>" element. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

html

```
<li id=list11><a>1.1</a></li>
```

css

```
#list11{
//apply formatting here
}
```